# Vue apollo add results to array

Tags: vue.js, apollo

This is probably just a basic vue question, but I am using Vue Apollo.
I have this component that is setup like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Products",
  components: { Product },
  props: {
    categorySlug: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const { categorySlug } = toRefs(props);
    const page = ref(1);
    const skip = ref(0);
    const result = reactive({ search: null, laoding: null, error: null });

    Object.assign(result, useListProducts(categorySlug.value, page.value));

    const more = () => {
      skip.value += 12;
      page.value += 1;

      Object.assign(result, useListProducts(categorySlug.value, page.value));
    };

    return { ...toRefs(result), ...{ skip, more } };
  },
});
```

As you can see I have a reactive object setup which is assigned to when the component setup method is invoked:

```
const result = reactive({ search: null, laoding: null, error: null });

Object.assign(result, useListProducts(categorySlug.value, page.value));
```

In my template, I iterate over the results like this:

```
<base-fade-up class="row" :duration="0.1" tag="div">
  <v-col
    cols="12"
    xl="2"
    v-for="(product, index) in products"
    :key="product.id"
    :data-index="index"
    :data-skip="skip"
  >
    <product class="product" :product="product"></product>
  </v-col>
</base-fade-up>
```

The problem I have, is that I want to add a more button:

```
<v-btn color="primary" @click="more()" v-if="search.hasMoreResults"
  >Show more</v-btn
>
```

When pressed, it executes the **more()** method:

```
const more = () => {
  skip.value += 12;
  page.value += 1;

  Object.assign(result, useListProducts(categorySlug.value, page.value));
};
```

As you can see, I am now getting **page 2**, so page one products are no longer in the **search** object.
What I would like to do is get a copy of the products from the first query and then add to them every time the more button is pressed.
I tried this:

```
setup(props) {
  const { categorySlug } = toRefs(props);
  const page = ref(1);
  const skip = ref(0);
  const products = ref([]);
  const result = reactive({ search: null, laoding: null, error: null });

  Object.assign(result, useListProducts(categorySlug.value, page.value));

  const more = () => {
    skip.value += 12;
    page.value += 1;

    Object.assign(result, useListProducts(categorySlug.value, page.value));
  };

  products.value.push(result.search.value.items);

  return { ...toRefs(result), ...{ products, skip, more } };
},
```

but when I run this code, I get an error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

which is complaining about `result.search.value` in this line:

```
products.value.push(result.search.value.items);
```

I believe it's because the promise has not been resolved.
I am using Apollo's **useResult** method inside my **useListProducts** which looks like this:

```
import { useQuery, useResult } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import * as listProducts from "@/graphql/api/query.products.gql";

export function useListProducts(slug: string, page = 1, itemsToShow = 12) {
  const request: {
    identifier?: string;
    searchTerm: string;
    itemsToShow: number;
    page: number;
    filters: any;
    facets: string[];
  } = {
    searchTerm: "*",
    itemsToShow,
    page,
    filters: [
      {
        key: "CategorySlug",
        value: `'${slug}'`,
      },
    ],
    facets: ["Criteria/Attribute,count:100"],
  };

  const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(listProducts, {
    search: request,
  });
  const search = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.search);
  return { search, loading, error };
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It needs a closer look but you shouldn't access things that aren't available on initialization in `setup` body, unless it uses suspense. Hooks (use...) should occur only in `setup`, not `more`. `products.value.push(result.search.value.items)` belongs to watch or watchEffect and need to be checked if they are available with conditional statements. `const result = ... Object.assign(result ...` - this makes no sense, there's already an object that useListProducts returns, it doesn't benefit from being assigned to `result`, this doesn't make it more reactive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to vue, so while I do appreciate your post, it doesn't help me at all :(

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, I found something in the documentation about pagination (which is essentially what I am doing), so because of that I managed to adjust my code to this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Products",
  components: { Product },
  props: {
    categorySlug: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const { categorySlug } = toRefs(props);
    const page = ref(1);
    const skip = ref(0);
    const { search, loading, error, fetchMore } = useListProducts(
      categorySlug.value,
      page.value
    );

    const more = () => {
      skip.value += 12;
      page.value += 1;

      const request = {
        ...params,
        ...{
          page: page.value,
          filters: [
            {
              key: "CategorySlug",
              value: `'${categorySlug.value}'`,
            },
          ],
        },
      };
      fetchMore({
        variables: { search: request },
        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
          if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
          //return fetchMoreResult;
          console.log(fetchMoreResult);
          return Object.assign({}, prev, {
            search: {
              hasMoreResults: fetchMoreResult.search.hasMoreResults,
              total: fetchMoreResult.search.total,
              facets: [...prev.search.facets, ...fetchMoreResult.search.facets],
              items: [...prev.search.items, ...fetchMoreResult.search.items],
              __typename: prev["__typename"],
            },
          });
        },
      });
    };

    return { search, loading, error, skip, more };
  },
});
```

Which satisfies everything Estus mentioned in the comments, but it does throw an error, which I will create a new post about :D